# how to disable 302 redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, ubuntu

My website is hosted on a VPS powered by Ubuntu with LAMP.

I can't use direct links to any page without `www`.

that is typing url http://example.com/secondpage will redirect to http://www.example.com/.
the second page had lost. But http://www.example.com/secondpage works perfectly.
I tried changing `.htaccess`, but no effect.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this inside your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If this doesn't work, you can use this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: as I already mentioned, its already tried these...
but no effect.
:(

Comment: @KrishnaRajK Where did you keep your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Consult with your web hosting provider, if they allow 301 redirect using `.htaccess` and also make sure, to check your cPanel settings for the same... :)

Comment: its not a just hosting server.
its a vps.
there is no cpanel.
wat we change in the os will surely reflect on the server.